# Is “My name is Smith” a clause?

Tags: parts-of-speech, clauses

My name is Smith.

I believe that it has a subject and verb, so I think it's an independent clause. Is this sentence an independent clause?

Comment: I think of "clause" as meaning a whole sentence included within another whole sentence,  thus: "I told him my name is Smith." The clause "my name is Smith" is a whole sentence, and here it is included as part of another whole sentence, so it's a clause. A conjunction connecting it with the larger sentence may also be considered part of the clause, thus, in "That's because my name is Smith.", the conjunction is "because". In "I'm in charge and my name is Smith." the conjunction is "and". In "I told him that my name is Smith.", the conjunction is "that".

Comment: I wonder if the conjunction would be considered part of the clause only if it's a subordinating conjunction, like "because" and "that" in the examples above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a clause. A sentence can consist of a single independent clause. It does not have to be part of a larger sentence to be a clause. It would become a dependent clause if it was introduced with a subordinating conjunction such as "because" or "if." I get many wrong number calls because my name is Smith. Here, "my name is Smith" is still a clause because it has a subject and a verb. But it is a dependent clause because of the subordinating conjunction "because."

"My name is Smith" could also be an independent clause in a sentence that also has a dependent clause. My name is Smith because one of my ancestors was a blacksmith.

You can have two independent clauses in the same sentence if they are joined by a coordinating conjunction such as "and," "but," or "yet." Many people ignore this, but I believe you should always put a comma before the coordinating conjunction that joins two independent clauses in the same sentence. My name is Smith, and my partner's name is Jones.